How to match PDF okular colors with Terminal colors?
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
okular  21.12.3
konsole 21.12.3
to display above:
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'
okular  -version
konsole -version
outputs:
ok match color Blue        in Terminal with Blue      in okular  
no match color BrightWhite in Terminal with DullWhite in okular  
               BrightWhite in Terminal = tput setaf 7 in bash  


image1,desired colors, Terminal Output:
.

image2,undesired colors, PDF okular output, converts BrightWhite to DullWhite:
.
okular shortcut Invert key is:
Ctrl-Alt-i
or
okular menu to change color:
Okular/Settings/ConfigureOkular/Accessibility/ChangeColors/DropDownMenu/...
Color Mode: Normal Colors           = WhitePagePdf  
Color Mode: Invert Luma (Symmetric) = BlackPagePdf  
...   

okular Ctrl-Alt-i
Color Mode: Invert Luma (Symmetric)  = BlackPagePdf
is a close match to Terminal screen, except for

BrightWhite in Terminal is DullWhite in okular
extra Linefeeds

Procedure1:
How to Save the Terminal Output to a Pdf File in Linux?
Konsole terminal / File / Save output as … Ctrl-Shift-s /
HTML document
a.html
open a.html in browser
ctrl-P
PDF Landscape / save as PDF
a.html.pdf
open a.html.pdf with okular
okular Ctrl-Alt-i to change colors
Color Mode: Normal Colors           = WhitePagePdf  
Color Mode: Invert Luma (Symmetric) = BlackPagePdf  
...   

How to match PDF okular colors with Terminal colors?
--

How about screen capture, pasting the image into an image editor, saving the file and pasting into Okular? OCR to get text. Or use another tool than Okular.

How about screen capture? screen capture might work for a task
that is a one-time task, for a single screen.
The task at hand is not a single screen and not a one-time task.
Above Procedure1 is relatively easy and
many PDF colors do match and
PDF copy text works.
Procedure1 drawbacks are:
some PDF colors do not match and
too many Linefeeds in PDF.

A Question for another time, regarding
bash script.sh  |&  tee /tmp/out.txt
How to cat /tmp/out.txt  to PDF with matching colors ?
